# Laravel package development: No hint path defined for [breadcrumbs]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have written a CMS package and am writing a bolt-on module to add events functionality.

Both of these packages use the Laravel [Breadcrumbs library](https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs).

This is part of the service provider for the events module:

```php
class EventsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // boot method

    // register method
    public function register()
    {
       $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/routes/web.php');
    }
}
```

Breadcrumbs for the core CMS package all work fine until I try and load the additional breadcrumb routes for this events module package:

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/routes/web.php');
    $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/routes/breadcrumbs.php');
}
```

This then stops all breadcrumb routes from working and the following error is encountered:

> No hint path defined for [breadcrumbs]. (View: /Users/*****/Sites/****/CMS (Package)/src/views/admin/news/create.blade.php)

Comment: I'm not sure the company and client names are related to the issue, but thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by checking for the class and loading the routes in the `boot` method instead:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
  if (class_exists('Breadcrumbs')) {
       require __DIR__ . '/routes/breadcrumbs.php';
    }
}
```